# Memory consumption in CF vs Full Framework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, memory-management

I was wondering if the memory consumption is different in the Full Framework vs the Compact Framework for types and classes that are compatible in between both.
I would also like to know if I target an assembly for the compact framework (a .dll library), and reference it in the desktop machine. Will it use the types from the full framework or the compact. If it is the latter, I assume that the memory consumption should be the same but is it?
My intuition is that compact framework types are simpler as they often have less methods, and many classes are missing. But are the memory representation per object the same? Does this depend on the architecture? (Running it on ARM vs x86 for example)
Is there a resource where I can find more information about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends a whole lot on the specifics of what you're looking at.  For example, if I have a simple object:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then it's in-memory representation is going to be the same under either framework.

If, however, I derive from a more complex class that is fundamentally different between the two frameworks, the results will then be different between the frameworks.

If loaded in the FFx, it's going to use the FFx assemblies to instantiate the instances, so even though it was compiled for the CF, the FFx will load it under the FFX runtimes, not the CF.

Processor architecture isn't going to matter, since these all compile to IL, which is processor-agnostic.

Of course, since you're talking memory consumption under managed code, how the GC works is a big factor too, and they work differently in the CF and FFx, so the footprint can be different for identical classes over time between the two framework all depending on usage patterns.

Comment: If the class had a byte property instead of an int property, would the auto-generated fields be mapped out sequentially on a mobile platform, as opposed to a on-a-boundary mapping on a non-mobile platform?

Comment: If the first was a byte, there would be a 3-byte "pad" between it and the string data in memory.  I'm surprised the full framework doesn't do the same (at least that's what I think you're saying it does) due to perf penalties for non-aligned accesses, but I've never really had a need to look hard at how the full framework lays stuff out since it's marshaler is robust enough that I rarely have to hand marshal stuff.  Not so lucky in the CF.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I assume then that it will always consume the same or less in CF but never more than in the FF. Right?

Comment: "Never" is too absolute.  I could probably contrive some edge-case scenario to make the CF take up more but I'm comfortable saying that it would be a rare case where the FFx would ever take up less than the CF.